# Setting Title in PDF from coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, accessibility

I have the following code in a coldfusion website.

```
<cfoutput>
    <cfdocument format="PDF">
      <html>
        <head>
          <title>
           ABC123
          </title>
        </head>
        <body>123</body>
      </html>
    </cfdocument>
</cfoutput>
```

We are trying to meeting accessibility requirements.
Inside of Edge no Title is being. Can I ask for guidance on setting this title?

We do not want to write to an intermediate file. The requirement is different than the question linked as duplicate.